# merge two arrays to be adjecent alement from other array - javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two javascript arrays of same size:

```
let a = [1,2,3,4,5]
let b = [6,7,8,9,10]
```

I want to merge this in the way:

```
let out = [1,6,2,7,3,8,4,9,5,10] //no adjecent elements from same array
```

Currently, I iterate them through a loop:

```js
let a = [1,2,3,4,5]
let b = [6,7,8,9,10]
let out = []
for(let i =0;i<a.length;i++){
    out.push(a[i])
    out.push(b[i])
}
console.log(out)
```

Is there a different/ better way to do the merge?

Comment: Use `a.concat(b)`

Comment: push accepts multiple elements `out.push(a[i], b[i])`

Comment: a.concat(b) does not merge the two arrays in a way where the items alternate! This is not the right solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relatively new array method [`.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) can be used here. It allows you to map values to arrays, which are then flattened into the larger resulting array. Here you can map each value from `a` to an array containing itself with its corresponding value in `b` using the index. This array will then form part of the larger resulting array:

```js
let a = [1,2,3,4,5]
let b = [6,7,8,9,10]
let out = a.flatMap((v, i) => [v, b[i]]);
console.log(out)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to merge the both arrays in desired format:

```js
let a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let b = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

let merge = (a1, a2) => a1.reduce((r, v, i) => r.concat(v, a2[i]), []);

console.log(merge(a, b));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

An alternate approach could be use of [`.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) inside callback:

```js
let a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let b = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

let merge = (a1, a2) => a1.reduce((r, v, i) => (r.push(v, a2[i]), r), []);

console.log(merge(a, b));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```